# Who registers a Microsoft Azure Active Directory APP? SaaS Provider or Customer?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal

a company provides an app to multiple customers with multiple users. Now the provider wants to let the users use their Microsoft Azure Active Directory to let their users login with their Microsoft credentials.
Is integrating the client with ADAL the right way?
What does the provider and what do the customers have to do to make this possible? The provider registers his app and then the customers grant this app permission? Or do the customers register the app and give the provider some keys?

Thank you very much for any help. Microsoft has so much documentation, but it is so difficult to get the information I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider should register the app.
Note you must register the app as multi-tenanted.

When another organisation tries to login, they'll be presented with a consent screen, where they must accept the permissions your app requires.

Then in your app, you can further check if this organisation has access to a subscription etc.

Check the multi-tenant guidance for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How does the adminstrator of the customer give the client the permission to check whether a user may login or not?

Comment: By default regular users can consent to 3rd party applications. If you require permissions that require admin consent or their admins have disabled regular user consent, then an admin needs to be the first one to sign in. If you use ADAL and the v1 endpoint, then you should use prompt=admin_consent in the authorization URL when you want an admin to be able to consent to the app. Also admins get the option to "Consent on behalf of organization" during regular login too.